# Links on tags on stackexchange.com are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

On stackexchange.com, logged in as myself on the "my tag sets" tab, I see a list titled "Or, browse popular tag sets". In each item, next to the "x Views" box, I see a list of tags starting with "All sites". The tags are links, e.g. hgrc links to https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hgrc. However, this resource throws a 404.

The same is true of all the tag links I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops. We were using stackexchange.com to represent the "All Sites" site, and never noticed that this caused us to generate invalid urls for "All Sites" tags.

I removed the `<a>` around "All Sites" tags. Thanks :)