# Tag links are broken on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, tags, hyperlinks, stackexchange.com, 404-not-found

Search results on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=bug) may contain questions which have tags.

> [image: tag]

These tags are clickable, but [refer to 404 page](https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability).

Seems related to old one: [Links on tags on stackexchange.com are broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75485/339911)